# How to set up vpn so that it only works on custom urls in linux

Tags: linux, networking, ip, vpn

I want to let my network manager to connects to all websites through the VPN except some custom urls.

The problem is that using route setting you can set up urls that you want to connect to not excluding them. I also searched a lot about this and couldn't find anything related. Now my question is that even if this is possible and it yes how can I achieve this? thanks in advanced.

P.S. I'd gladly delete the question if there's any duplicate in all SE forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all  When you route all of your traffic through VPN, You have a route to `0.0.0.0/0`
It means any request with any destination should go through it.
Alternatively you can exclude the rule with adding a rule routing your special destination, lets say `192.168.1.20` via your local gateway, lets say `192.168.1.1`
you could add this:

```
ip route add 192.168.1.20/32 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
```

`eth0` in this case is your network interface.